# Concatenating strings in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

With the code below, looking at the 2nd paragraph in particular...if var str = "sting equality test..." + strA, why do the 2nd, 3rd lines etc not output that same output plus their own line?

EDIT sorry for not explaining properly - I am actually just wondering why this code (once I have cleaned it up) DOESN'T produce the first line (of the 2nd paragraph) repeated, plus whatever I state in the 2nd and 3rd lines etc. I don't need it to, it's just an exercise, I just don't understand. It seems as though it should

```
function init()
{
    var strA = "Javascript" === "JAVASCRIPT" ;
    var strB = "Javascript" === "Javascript" ;
    var flt = 7.5 === 7.5 ;
    var intA = 8 !== 8 ;
    var intB = 24 > 12 ;
    var intC = 24 < 12 ;
    var intD = 24 <= 24 ;

    var str = "String equality test: " + strA ;
    str += "<br>String equality test 2: " + strB ;
    str += "<br>Float equality test: " ; + strC ;
    str += "<br>Integer inequality test: " + intA ;
    str += "<br>Greater than test: " + intB ;
    str += "<br>Less than test: " + intC ;
    str += "<br>Less than/Equal to test: " + intD ;

    document.getElementById( "panel" ).innerHTML = str ;
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" , init , false) ;
```

So the output I get is as follows;

String equality test: false
String equality test 2: true
Float equality test: true
Integer inequality test: false
Greater than test: true
Less than test: false
Less than/Equal to test: true

This is obviously correct, I just don't understand how something like the following isn't outputted because surely I am adding each line to the var str, which is "String equakity test: false

```
 String equality test: false
String equality test: false String equality test 2: true
String equality test: false Float equality test: true
String equality test: false Integer inequality test: false
String equality test: false Greater than test: true
String equality test: false Less than test: false
String equality test: false Less than/Equal to test: true
```

Comment: Why have you got a mysterious floating `;` in the third line?

Comment: ^^ because there is no strC ?

Comment: @Jeffman: was that a response to me, or the OP? DJC: if you'd looked at your Web Developer tools (F12 in most browsers) they would have told you this. Also, pressing the 'JS Hint' button, if you'd put together a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: @David Both, I guess. To OP, the undefined variable might be a problem. To you, the seemingly stray ; might be a misguided attempt at short-circuiting the concatenation of a value that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I just don't understand how something like the following isnt outputted because surely I am adding each line to the var `str`, which is `"String equakity test: false"`*

No, the only time that `str` is equal to `"String equality test: false"` is immediately after the first line. Each line modifies the `str` variable by adding something to whatever it became after the line before.  So after the first line:

```
var str = "String equality test: " + strA ;
```

...the variable `str` is now equal to

```
"String equality test: false"
```

Then after the second line:

```
str += "<br>String equality test 2: " + strB ;
```

...the variable `str` is now equal to

```
"String equality test: false<br>String equality test 2:"
```

The third line has an error, but assuming you remove the extra semicolon and fix the variable name:

```
str += "<br>Float equality test: " ; + strC ;
// should be
str += "<br>Float equality test: " + flt;
```

...then the variable `str` will be equal to

```
"String equality test: false<br>String equality test 2: true<br>Float equality test: true"
```

...and so forth.

You can see this clearly if you add a `console.log(str);` statement in between each line and open your browser's console before running the code. As shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/mfKy9/

Comment: thanks for that, very clear and helpful. i was just getting confused with the += , thinking it was keeping the line then adding the next, whereas like you say, it is actually replacing the previous value of var str. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a `;` on the third line in front of the `+`. Removing that should solve the problem. The variable `strC` which you try to add after that strange `+` doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks, have changed that now, but please see my edit, sorry for not explaining properly first time around

Comment: @DJC, you mean your code still doesn't output all lines after solving the problems I mentioned?

Comment: This is an exercise from a book and I am trying to understand why the var str, when used in the 2nd, 3rd line etc doesn't include the "string equality test" bit as isn't that what I have defined it as. The other lines look as though they should produce that, then the added values they contain?

Comment: Can you add your exact output and your expected output to the question?

Comment: sorry for delay, will edit question with expected and actual output. thanks forthe help, much appreciated